# Surrounding 2 or more columns of text with other text

Tags: string, debugging, excel, coldfusion

I'm debugging some ColdFusion code (although the question is really language-agnostic), and from the debug output, have two columns of text.

Those columns are **field name** `<tab>` **value** and want to be able to quickly convert this into test code.

**The text I start off with:**

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
etc
```

**The code I want to end up with:**

```
structInsert(myStruct, "a", 1);
structInsert(myStruct, "b", 2);
structInsert(myStruct, "c", 3);
etc
```

Ordinarily, I'd use Excel, pasting the two columns of data into columns A and B, and create a formula in column C that concatenates A and B something like

```
="structInsert(myStruct, """ & A1 & """, " & B1 & ");"
```

This works fine (and is one of the main reasons I love Excel).

But I'm wondering... given that the whole world doesn't have Excel, how does everyone else do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I like to do with Notepad++ or Eclipse with search and replace feature with regular expression.

Like search for 
([a-z]*)\t(\d)
replace with
structInsert(myStruct,"\1",\2);

So simple.. right?

Comment: Wow... that IS great :) I've never used back-references like that before... didn't realise it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with regular expressions.

In CFEclipse/CFBuilder open the Find/Replace dialogue

Find:  ^(.+?)\t(.+?)$
Replace with: structInsert(myStruct, "$1", $2);
Check Regular Expressions
Click Replace All

Comment: Yeah, that's great too. Thanks Chris. Sorry that I can't mark two answers as correct, but it's really useful to know how to do that in CFEclipse. Cheers.

Comment: Not a big issue for a one-off thing like this, but in general a more efficient regex would be `^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)$`